# Cannot play flash in android web view after many try

Tags: android, flash, webview, android-video-player, video-player

I am doing an android app which shows my website in the webview. My website contains a flash player for playing movie.

[Here](http://vnxine.com/xem-phim/online/nguoi-may-cody/250263.html) is the link which contains the flash player and I want to display on the webview.

After reading many articles, I have tried the following code:

```
webview2.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview2.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webview2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview2.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

But it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound very simple, but make sure the platform you're testing this on has the Flash Player installed.

Comment: would you please try a android sample to display my link in webview. actually , I tried ! but it failed !

Answer (score 0):

Many android phones do not have flash player in their browsers anymore, and there isnt a flash player plugin for the WebView object.

Your best chance would be to make this video in your page viewed with html5 video tags, or let people view your website in their own browser, which may or may not work (some browsers have flash, some dont)